# SQL Server LIKE operator not matching values containing square brackets

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-like

I have a table in my database where I  inserted all table names in my database. 
For example I have table name [test].[TestTable] and when I run this query

```
select * from Tables where Name like N'%[test].[TestTable]%'
```

it doesn't return any value but  this query works:

```
select * from Tables where Name like N'%[TestTable]%'
```

Can someone explain me why?

Comment: SQL Server already contains metadata "tables" that describe the objects within each database. Why are you building your own?

Comment: And a hint - for the `LIKE` operator, both `[` and `]` have special meaning.

Comment: The first part before the name is probably a schema name. It's not a tables name per se.

Comment: You may also want to read up on the _escape character_ used with [`like`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#pattern-matching-with-the-escape-clause).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to escape the left square bracket:

```
SELECT * FROM Tables WHERE Name LIKE N'%[[]test].[[]TestTable]%' 
-----------------------------------------^        ^
--------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

when u use the operator LIKE and in the condition add [], it has another meaning. LIKE "reads" it as any single character within the specified range ([a-f]) or set ([abcdef]).

try using: like N'%TestTable%'